# Do I have to manually decode an uploaded text file in web2py to the Python type 'unicode'?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, web2py

(Using web2py 2.10.4.) I have an uploaded text file, coming from a form:

```
if upload_form.process(formname='upload_form').accepted:
    file_value = upload_form.vars.file.value
```

The `file.value` attribute turns out to be the old Python 2 str type (bytes), and not `<type 'unicode'>`:

```
> type(upload_form.vars.file.value)
<type 'str'>
```

At the moment, I'm calling `file_value.decode()` with a long (and getting longer) list of codecs -- default, utf-8-sig, windows-1252 -- in an attempt to decode the uploaded file properly.

My questions:

1. How does web2py internally handle uploaded files? Is it pure bytes?
2. What is the best
   practice for grabbing the text content of an uploaded text file -- guessing using a bunch of common encodings?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. File data *by definition* is bytes. What are you doing with this data that it matters?

Comment: @DanielRoseman: The file I'm working with is text, so I intend to process it as text, and not bytes. If I were opening the file myself, I'd know to decode the bytes, but web2py doesn't document its way of handling an uploaded file, so I'm checking to see if it's doing anything with uploaded files.

Comment: Why guess? Did you check the request headers?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: Didn't think that was an option. :) Is that passed in the request header?

Comment: Hrm, no it wouldn't be, because the file already exists as bytes on disk. Never mind.